# (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK) locks whole table even tough only 1 row is selected

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, locking

Inside our Java application we are using a *SQL Server* statement to pause some processes.

This is the SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM MESSAGES WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK) 
WHERE MESSAGES.INTERNAL_ID IN ('6f53448f-1c47-4a58-8839-e126e81130f0');
```

The UUIDs in the `IN` clause changes of course from run to run.

This the Java code we use for locking:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlString).getResultList()
```

The above SQL statement returns only one row. Unfortunately it seems that the whole table gets locked. The result is that all processes are locked even though none or only some should be blocked.

Why is the whole table locked even though I specify `UPDLOCK`?

---

Additional information:

- `MESSAGES.INTERNAL_ID` is `NVARCHAR(255)` which is not nullable.
  Otherwise there is no constraint on the column.
- The isolation level is `READ_COMMITTED`.

Comment: Provide definition of `messages` table (Is ID a primary key?) what is your transaction isolation level?

Comment: @MikhailLobanov I've added the requested information to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your `MESSAGES.INTERNAL_ID` is not a key. Once row is locked you cannot read it and check it's value. Try to create a primary key on this column.

If it's impossible, create `INDEX` on it and rewrite your query:

```
SELECT MESSAGES.INTERNAL_ID FROM MESSAGES WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK) 
WHERE MESSAGES.INTERNAL_ID IN ('6f53448f-1c47-4a58-8839-e126e81130f0');
```

MSDN says:

> Lock hints ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, AND XLOCK that acquire row-level locks
>   **may** place locks on **index keys** rather than the actual data rows. For
>   example, if a table has a nonclustered index, and a SELECT statement
>   using a lock hint is handled by a covering index, a lock is acquired
>   on the index key in the covering index rather than on the data row in
>   the base table.

Comment: Thank you! I'm now using the primary key for locking and it works.

Comment: Just another question: Is the `SELECT MESSAGES.ID` the important part or `WHERE MESSAGES.ID`?

Comment: If you create primary key it's not important. PK usually is a clustered index (clustered index is always covering). But if you'd create a nonclusterd index, you should be careful with select list.